# ImportError: cannot import name celery

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm trying to run some background jobs using Celery + Redis + Flask.

My app structure is:

```
myapp/
  celery_worker.py
  manage.py
  myapp/
    __init__.py
    app.py
    bot/
      __init__.py
      tasks.py
    accounts/
      views.py
```

I initialise celery into app.py as:

```
celery = Celery('tasks', include=['bot.tasks'])

def create_app(config=None, app_name=None, blueprints=None):
    # more Celery and other config here like celery.conf.update()
```

And start worker by `celery_worker.py`

```
from myapp import create_app, celery

app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()
```

`tasks.py` contains

```
from myapp import celery

@celery.task(name='my_task_bot')
def my_task_bot():
     # pass
```

Now, when I try to access tasks from tasks.py into accounts/views.py with following import:

```
from ..bot.tasks import my_task_bot
```

I getting `ImportError: cannot import name celery` error.

No matter, where I try to import tasks, I'm getting this error. This `celery` instance seems to be the one initialised in app.py, but is not getting imported.

PS: I'm following pattern of https://github.com/ezequielo/flask_celery_exp repo and it works fine. But not my app.

**Edit:**

Here is Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from myapp import create_app
  File "/home/mars/myapp/myapp/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import create_app, celery
  File "/home/mars/myapp/myapp/app.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .accounts import (accounts, AccountsAdmin) 
  File "/home/mars/myapp/myapp/accounts/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .views import accounts
  File "/home/mars/myapp/myapp/accounts/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..bot.tasks import my_task_bot
  File "/home/mars/myapp/myapp/bot/tasks.py", line 14, in <module>
    from myapp import celery
ImportError: cannot import name celery

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'python manage.py initdb'
```

I get above error on trying to start any of either `manage.py` or `celery_worker`.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your import logic is not correct and leads to circular dependency. Do not initialize celery in app.py together with reference to the module (`accounts`) that in turn imports `celery` instance.

You have several options:

1. Remove dependency from app `accounts` at app.py module
2. Put celery initialization object into shared module that does not refer to any other modules, but referred by `/*/tasks.py` submodules.
3. Do not import celery in tasks, but use `shared_task` decorator. For more info refer to [doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-the-shared-task-decorator)

**Important:** Do not forget to proper link celery app to your @shared_tasks. Celery application should be loaded before any task. For that reason define celery initialization in celery.py and then load it at `myapp/__init__.py`.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from .celery import app as celery_app  # noqa
```

Alternatively you can elaborate more on this [link](https://github.com/inveniosoftware-attic/flask-appfactory/tree/master/examples/myapp). It shows a good way of organizing your flask app together with celery app.

Comment: now, i'm getting `socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused` error when trying to run tasks from flask app. is it to do with @shared_task? as in documentation it's mentioned that this decorator creates tasks without any concrete instance

Comment: No celery doc means by that "The @shared_task decorator lets you create tasks that can be used by any app(s).". I am using it in the following way in pyramid, flask, django. Could you provide more details? Which brocker do you use? if redis, are u sure it is running? Would be better if you provide configuration details.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fcfd7b4fe6af8661822c38773b0612a2 The periodic task runs properly and 'celery status' commands gives +ve result. Only problem is when I try to call/run a command based on user input (in flask app, say form/button click), then I get this `Connection refused` error.

Comment: I see. It means that your task is loaded before celery app and then there is no proper linking between shared_task and your celery app. You can try to import celery into `myapp.__init__` module. but for that you need to resolve bug with circular imports. Then I am sure your celery is loaded before actual tasks and link proper setup. Hope it helps

Comment: Added Important section in answer

Comment: btw how do you launch celery app ?

Comment: As I've a `celery_worker.py` file in root, I go to that directory and do `celery -A celery_worker.celery worker -B -l INFO` and after that I start my flask app. Also when Celery starts, I get all my tasks listed in celery. So, does that mean still my tasks are not loaded, as per your previous comments?

Comment: I moved my Celery init to a submodule at `myapp/myapp/celeryapp/__init__.py` and now can load it to `tasks.py`, `celery_worker.py` and everything works fine! Thanks a lot @Rustem K

Answer (score 2):

tasks.py

```
from myapp.app import celery
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Already tried above, but still getting same `ImportError`. I've updated trackback in original question. See that.

Comment: true, see my answer

Comment: I see. It means that your task is loaded before celery app and then there is no proper linking between shared_task and your celery app. You can try to import celery in `myapp.__init__` module:

Answer (score 1):

In the file that you initialise Celery, add this as the first line.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Explanation

`from __future__ import absolute_import` means that if you import celery, Python will look for a top-level celery module, rather than current_package.celery. This should possibly fix the error you are getting. But make sure celery is 
installed. It good to mention celery must be installed. This works for 
python version later than 2.6

Answer (score 0):

i resolve this error uncheck 'add content roots to python path' and 'add soruce roots to python path' in pycharm